# How to find MIN,MAX,FIRST,LAST in one MysQl query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below

```
products

 id  price  date 
-------------------------------
 1    1     2018-04-27 12:10:15
 2    2     2018-04-27 12:10:15
 3    5     2018-04-27 12:10:18
 4    3     2018-04-27 12:10:18
 5    4     2018-04-27 12:11:25
 6    3     2018-04-27 12:11:25
```

**Note :** I have to find min price,max price, starting price,ending price of every minute.

My expected output is

```
firstPrice lastPrice minPrice maxPrice
---------------------------------------
    1          3         1       5     --> Grouped for (2018-04-27 12:10)
    4          3         3       4     --> Grouped for (2018-04-27 12:11)
```

My query is

```
SELECT b.lastPrice,c.firstPrice,min(a.price) as minPrice,max(a.price) as maxPrice from products as a left join (select price as lastPrice,date from products order by date desc) as b on a.date = b.date left join (select price as firstPrice,date from products order by date asc) as c on a.date = c.date where a.date >= '2018-04-27 12:10:00'
```

I don't know what to do to get the expected output.

Comment: You don't have a group by and its not stated  from your expected output what you group by.(possibly datetime?)

Comment: hi Salmon, I have updated my question. I'm new to these kind of join queries. I'm stuck with this query.

Comment: One more detail to take into account: You want to group by date and get min/max/... for each MINUTE while (apparently) your field is of type datetime, which includes seconds and fraction of seconds. You will need to either create another column that holds datetime to **MINUTE** resolution or convert your field to that for, and only then you will be able to correctly `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Actually I have to do group by minute. so that I will get min,max,first,last price details for each of the minute's records.

Comment: Hi @FDavidov , I tried with `group by YEAR(a.date),MONTH(a.date),DAY(a.date),HOUR(a.date),MINUTE(a.date)` . But no luck

Comment: Of course that would NOT work!!!! You need to create a field like `YEAR(a.date)+MONTH(a.date)+DAY(a.date)+HOUR(a.date)+MIN(a.date)` and then group by this field.

Comment: By the way, make sure that the HOUR returns in 24 hours form.

Comment: Ok @FDavidov , I will try and let you know.

Comment: why  you have firts price = 4 in the second  row of your result? .. which is the logic?

Comment: @scaisEdge - looks like value of `price` column with the lowest `id` with date `2018-04-27 12:11` (group by minute)

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge , I have added a description in my expected output field. I hope it's now able to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT price FROM products WHERE DATE_FORMAT(p.`date`, '%Y%m%d%H%i') = DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m%d%H%i') ORDER BY `date` ASC, id ASC LIMIT 1) AS firstPrice,
    (SELECT price FROM products WHERE DATE_FORMAT(p.`date`, '%Y%m%d%H%i') = DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m%d%H%i') ORDER BY `date` DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1) AS lastPrice,
    MIN(price) AS minPrice, MAX(price) AS maxPrice 
FROM products p 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m%d%H%i')
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a989/15/0

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Your code works perfect. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this where first and last price are acquired in sub queries using a limit clause and grouped by date.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int,  price int , dt datetime);
insert into t values
( 1  ,  1  ,   '2018-04-27 12:10:15'),
( 2  ,  2  ,   '2018-04-27 12:10:15'),
( 3  ,  5  ,   '2018-04-27 12:10:18'),
( 4  ,  3  ,   '2018-04-27 12:10:18'),
( 5  ,  4  ,   '2018-04-27 12:11:25'),
( 6  ,  3  ,   '2018-04-27 12:11:25');


select concat(date(dt),' ',hour(dt), ':',minute(dt) ,':00') Timeslot,
         (select price from t t1 where concat(date(t1.dt),' ',hour(t1.dt), ':',minute(t1.dt) ,':00') = concat(date(t.dt),' ',hour(t.dt), ':',minute(t.dt) ,':00') order by id limit 1) firstprice,
         (select price from t t1 where concat(date(t1.dt),' ',hour(t1.dt), ':',minute(t1.dt) ,':00') = concat(date(t.dt),' ',hour(t.dt), ':',minute(t.dt) ,':00') order by id desc limit 1) lastprice,
         min(price),max(price)
from t
group by concat(date(dt),' ',hour(dt), ':',minute(dt) ,':00');

+---------------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Timeslot            | firstprice | lastprice | min(price) | max(price) |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 2018-04-27 12:10:00 |          1 |         3 |          1 |          5 |
| 2018-04-27 12:11:00 |          4 |         3 |          3 |          4 |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```